# Simplification of Radicals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Recently, I learn some basic factorisation techniques, but then there are sometimes where a messy radical will somehow cancel out into a clean one. Here is one I encountered:

$$\frac{3 \sqrt5 - 5}{3 - \sqrt5}$$

Results to $\sqrt5$.

Does anyone have any tips on how I can simplify these radicals, or does it simply require a calculator. Also, can someone fix the formating for me, I'm not sure how to do so.

Thank you!

Comment: Please, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: As stated is false. You probably need to add some parenthesis because $\displaystyle 3\sqrt{5}-\frac{5}{3}-\sqrt{5} \ne \sqrt{5}$

Comment: Multiply numerator and denominator by $3+\sqrt5.$

Comment: @jjagmath I added the missing parenthesis (34 seconds before your comment).

Comment: The strategy is to remember that $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$. So if you have $3-\sqrt 5$ in the denominator, you multiply by $3+\sqrt 5%=$ to get $3^2-(\sqrt 5)^2=9-5=4$

Comment: Stay simple: each term in the numerator is $\sqrt{5}$ times a corresponding term in the denominator, so just factor out that $\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: @AnneBauval We do not need conjugate here . Because, note that $$3\sqrt 5-5=\sqrt 5(3-\sqrt 5).$$

Comment: The 2 previous comments ate clever but I find it more instructive to apply the generic trick.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{3\sqrt 5-5}{3-\sqrt 5}\cdot\frac{3+\sqrt 5}{3+\sqrt 5}=\frac{9\sqrt 5+15-15-5\sqrt 5}{9-5}=\frac{4\sqrt 5}{4}=\sqrt 5$$